Backup program for Ubuntu
I switched from my Qnap NAS to an Ubuntu server because the NAS was lacking performance.
All is working fine and I've installed KDE plasma as desktop so it is userfriendly.
The only problem I'm encountering is, a GUI backup program to backup daily, weekly my Data to an external drive WITH messaging to email.
Just a message that backup was good or something was wrong.
I have tried lots of utilities and I think LuckyBackup is the one but I can't get the messaging working.
There are problems on the internet dating from 2012 with logging to email wit Luckybackup and I'm not able to get it working.
Also the cron tasks are admitted but when I add a file to the data folder, it doesn't appear in the backup folder.
Is there someone out there who can help me or has an alternative backup program which i haven't found yet?
Thank you
Tom

Be aware that the last release of LuckyBackup from its developers was six years ago. Their website has not been updated in five years. These clues suggest a dying or dead project. The packages may be removed from Debian (and thence Ubuntu) if the developers fail to respond to bugs or standards changes, which may leave you in a bit of a backup quandary.

Possible solution: Installing Timeshift backup on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of the linked duplicate question but you could make it into one by posting in answer that had the following bash command (requires mailutils package) in it as part of a shell script sudo timeshift --create --comments "Scheduled backup" --tags D && SUBJECT="Timeshift Backup Successful" || SUBJECT="Timeshift Backup Failed"; MESSAGE="The Timeshift backup was $([[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "completed successfully" || echo "encountered an error")."; echo "$MESSAGE" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" your_email@example.com

@karel the OP asked for an alternative - I suggested Timeshift and referenced a possible dupe.

@graham "The only problem I'm encountering is, a GUI backup program to backup daily, weekly my Data to an external drive WITH messaging to email." IMO that part of the question should be answered too (+ Timeshift optionally). That would make this a unique question.

@karel given that, this Unix & Linux post might be helpful to the OP in his deliberations. I can't see that TS handles emails itself but if called other than within the program, perhaps it could satisfy his need.

Ok, @user535733, you're right. I did NOT made a list of all programs which I have tried. I've tried the most obvious one's like Ubuntu backup, backintime TimeShift Kbackup, backup.   Ubuntu/Linux is is gaining popularity due to the 'lookalike' desktop as in Windows. So making backups using cmdlines is a bit for the specialists, not me.
